# JQuery-Steps: How to customize the next button for each step?

Tags: jquery-steps

I am using JQuery Steps, which works great. But I cannot figure out how to change the text on the "Next" button such that it's different for each step.  Is there a way to do that, maybe inside the onStepChanged method?

Answer (score 3):

this is your answer buddy:

```
$(function ()
{
    var settings = {
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            labels: 
            {
               next: "Enroll",
               finish: "Pay Now",
            },
        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
            {       
                //change color of the Go button
                //alert(currentIndex);
                if(currentIndex==1){
                $(".actions a:eq(1)").text("Checkout");
                }else{
                    $(".actions a:eq(1)").text("Enroll");
                }

            },

    };
    $("#wizard").steps(settings);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onStepChanged` is the right place for changing the text of the *Next* button. Unfortunately there is currently no good way to do that kind of stuff. Just search for the *Next* button with a selector like the following and change the text `wizard.find(".actions a:eq(1)").text("Next One")`. In version 2.0.0 will be a better way for doing such things.